# Phone application not found on Android emulator 18

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I could not find Phone (call) application on Android emulator 18. Where is it?

How to add Phone application to Android emulator 18?

[image]

Comment: try to create new emulator..

Comment: @Pankaj I created new emulator with API level 18. I still could not see Phone application!

Comment: i foud the same problem

Comment: Yes it seems that they missed that :) doc say that `Android 4.3 powers the new Nexus 7 tablet that's coming soon to Google Play and retail outlets, and it’s rolling out now as an update to Nexus 4, Nexus 7, Nexus 10, and Galaxy Nexus HSPA+ devices across the world.` and these tablets doesn't support phone. so that may be the reason of missing app. but not sure

Answer (score 1):

None of the Google provided emulators have the phone application.

As an alternative, you can use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/), where the emulators do include the ASOP phone application.